# Using Liquibase to version control remote SQLite Databases

Tags: liquibase

The system I have is a local machine for development with the dev DB and a number of remote servers with the production database. While looking for a system to manage the versions of my SQLite database I found Liquibase but I can't understand if it will work for what I need. Which is updating the schema of the production databases when i release a new version, adding the changes configured in Liquibase's changelog file for that version. Ofcourse all the rest code is under GIT so, if Liquibase only needs the changelog files I can put them in the repository, but if it needs something else it could become a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should work. If you are using liquibase for first time it will run all the migrations and will store information in your database by creating seperate table for itself. Though you should verify the structure at both local and production is same and migrations won't cause error.

Comment: Good to know, thank you! About the differences between the local and production DB it shouldn't be a problem, I've read that liquibase supports the creation of a script from an already existing database, so i'll use that and recreate the production databases and then I'll re-import the data, so everything should be fine